# How to split, compare, and find the difference from a concatenated list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to find the differences between two cells with concatenated values in each of them, then I'm trying to highlight the missing value in the column.

[image]

I tried just setting it up so cell A and B would each turn into arrays in order to compare their values.

```
=SORT(SPLIT(A1," "),1,TRUE))
```

Expected: CA, US, BR 
Actual: CA, US, BR

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ", ")), 
        ISNA(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ", ")), 
                   TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", ")), 0))))
```

[image: 1]

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much.